# Отключить компьютер в заданное время

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Я хочу, чтоб моя Ubuntu автоматически отключалась каждый день в определенное время. Как этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем трогать крон в системе с божественным systemd? :)

В systemd одним из способов выключения компьютера является включение службы `systemd-poweroff`, которая запускает команду `/bin/systemctl --force poweroff`, которая понятно что делает.

Сделаем таймер для запуска этой службы по расписанию, создав файл `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-poweroff.timer` (под рутом, разумеется):

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 23:03:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

(Формат даты `ДеньНедели Год-Месяц-День Часы:Минуты:Секунды`, день недели писать необязательно, звёздочка означает любое значение.)

Запустим его (таймер, а не выключение):

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-poweroff.timer
```

И добавим в автозагрузку, чтобы каждый раз вручную не запускать:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-poweroff.timer
```

Теперь этот таймер будет каждый день в 23:03 запускать ту службу, которая написана в имени файла — `systemd-poweroff` — и тем самым выключать компьютер.

С помощью команды `sudo systemctl status systemd-poweroff.timer` можно посмотреть информацию о таймере: точное время следующего запуска, оставшееся время и так далее:

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-poweroff.timer
* systemd-poweroff.timer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/systemd-poweroff.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2019-07-16 11:34:01 MSK; 10min ago
  Trigger: Tue 2019-07-16 23:03:00 MSK; 11h left

Jul 16 11:34:01 home systemd[1]: Started systemd-poweroff.timer.
```

Если вы отредактировали файл (например, изменили время), нужно выполнить `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` для применения изменений.

Подробнее про таймеры можно почитать [на арчевики](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/Timers_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

Answer (score 5):

На помощь нам придет юниксный демон по имени `cron`.
Для того, чтобы поставить задачу в расписание, мы добавим ее в файл `/etc/crontab`.
Открываем терминал   — <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>.
Файл можно редактировать такой командой:

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab
```

Для отключения компьютера каждый день в 23:03 добавим в файл такую строчку:

```
03 23 * * * root shutdown -h now
```

Последняя строчка файла должна быть **пустая**.

Эта часть была написана по мотивам  [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567955/automatic-shutdown-at-specified-times).

### **Объяснение подробнее**.

(**Обновлено**)

В самом этом файле `/etc/crontab` объясняется формат таблицы задач:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
```

Первые два поля — минута и час запуска задачи,
    3-е поле (dom)  — день месяца (Day of Month),
    затем месяц,
    5-е поле (dow)  — день недели,
    затем пользователь, от чьего имени будет запускаться команда,
    и, собственно, команда.

**Время запуска**
Все условия (времени запуска) проверяются по «логическому И», кроме условий «день недели» и «день месяца» — указанные совместно, они обрабатываются по «логическому ИЛИ», то есть «по любому из дней», что отражено в документации (Ubuntu, Debian, FreeBSD).  (См. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), `man 5 crontab`). Если вы хотите проверять их по «логическому И», делайте это в самой команде.

Например, перезагрузка в пятницу, 13-го:

```
0 0 13 * * root [ "$(date '+\%u')" -eq 5 ] && shutdown -r now
```

**`Crontab` пользователя**.
Кроме общей таблицы crontab, каждый пользователь имеет свою. 
Свою личную таблицу можно редактировать командой

```
crontab -e
```

Таблицу другого пользователя, например, 'root'-а, можно редактировать командой

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

В первоначальном вопросе правильнее, я думаю, было бы использовать именно этот вариант.
Если в системе есть всего один пользователь, то можно отключать компьютер и через него, и через   'root', без разницы.

Спасибо господам [0andriy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180002/0andriy) и [Sergey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213498/sergey), который привлекли мое внимание к такой возможности.

Обратите внимание, что в таблице конкретного пользователя формат задачи немного другой, там не нужно указывать пользователя.
Вместо

```
03 23 * * * root shutdown -h now
```

нужно писать

```
03 23 * * *  shutdown -h now
```

**Переменные окружения**
Популярная причина проблем с работой `crontab` -- другое определение переменных окружения при работе демона `cron`,
особенно  переменной `$PATH`.
Вы можете узнать переменные окружения `cron`-а, вставив в `crontab` строчку

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

После того, как файл `/tmp/env.output` создан, эту строчку можно убрать.
Оказывается, в Ubuntu `cron` запускается с `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`. 
Для корректной работы нужно определить правильный `$PATH` в самом файле `crontab`.
Обратите внимание, что значение переменных не подставляется, то есть

```
PATH = $HOME/bin:$PATH
```

не сработает.
Альтернативный способ решения этой проблемы -- использовать полные пути для запуска команд.  Но он хуже, если вы хотите проверить свою команду в  терминале или перенести в другую систему.

Если вы запускаете  программы с GUI, вам также надо определить $DISPLAY:

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

Да, и не забывайте в конце `crontab`-а вставлять **пустую строчку**.

Вторая часть ответа была написана по мотивам  [вопроса](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working) о проблемах работы с `crontab`-ом на askubuntu.
Спасибо всем комментаторам за плодотворную дискуссию.

Comment: Зачем `sudo` там, где это не требуется?

Comment: @0andriy без sudo файл /etc/crontab открывается только на чтение.

Comment: А кто вам говорит, что нужно использовать _/etc/crontab_? Нет, нет, про `cron` и в целом идея правильная.

Comment: @0andriy если у вас есть другое решение, оформите его как ответ. Вдруг кому-то подойдет? Вдруг мне подойдет больше, чем cron?

Comment: Решение у вас написано, только *root* не нужен. Учимся пользоваться Unix’ом вместе!

Comment: А почему не `sudo crontab -e`?

Comment: @0andriy **только root не нужен.** В самом деле?! А вот команда *$ ls -l /etc/crontab* говорит нечто совсем другое: *-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 722 апр  6  2016 /etc/crontab*. И по стилю. *Учимся пользоваться Unix’ом вместе!* - это Вы кому адресуете?

Comment: @Sergey, в самом деле. Почитайте в конце концов документацию, не надо демонстрировать своё невежество.

Comment: @0andriy Почитайте в конце концов вывод команды *$ ls -l /etc/crontab* , Вы знаете, что означают биты *rw-r--r--* ?  Не надо демонстрировать своё хамство.

Comment: @Sergey, я знаю, что означает вывод команды `ls -l`, также я знаю, что означает опция `-u`, передаваемая в команду `crontab`.

Comment: @0andriy Ввожу: *>  crontab -u root* и получаю: *must be privileged to use -u*. Вы знаете какой-то другой способ получения рядовым пользователем привилегий рута, кроме команды *sudo*?

Comment: @Sergey, ещё раз, *root* не нужен, зачем вы издеваетесь над Unix? Есть пользовательская таблица, там и пишите.

Comment: @0andriy шатдаун не выполнится не интерактивно в современной системе.

Comment: @user244413 зачем извращение с датой когда есть пятая звездочка (dow)?)

Comment: Вся часть ответа, начиная со строчки «Переменные окружения», совершенно не относится к вопросу. Выключение компьютера не использует каких-то особенных переменных окружения и уж точно никак не относится к GUI (не считая выключения иксов).

Comment: @andreymal, `$ which shutdown` дает `/sbin/shutdown`. Вставить одну строчку в `/etc/crontab`  -- самое простое решение, потому что там уже выставлен '$PATH`. А вот с 'crontab -e` мне пришлось долго разбираться, пока он заработал, и выводы попали в ответ.

Comment: @erl написано под заголовком **Время запуска**

Comment: @user244413 ну в /etc/crontab PATH всё-таки нормальный, а выключать компьютер (особенно сервер) не рутом это как-то странно и вообще запрещено в некоторых окружениях